# Gear oil pressure Nissan 2002

Tags: nissan, x-trail

Today a mechanic open the gauge of my Nissan xtrail 2002. There was a pressure in there that blown up the oil. The mechanic wasn't sure whats the problem. Help from you guys would be highly appreciated

Comment: you need to give a bit more information about this,was the overpressure when your engine was running or was the overpressure when the engine was stopped.

Comment: What « gauge » did the mechanic open?

Comment: I'm going to guess that he's talking about the rear differential. There is a vent to eliminate pressure. This vent is probably blocked.